# I can't see environment variable on Express App

Tags: node.js, express, environment-variables

Variables are setted in `.bashrc`. I can see them on terminal `$echo MY_VAR`. Also I can see them on `Node.js` shell `process.env.MY_VAR`. But I can't see it in my Express App.
`file.js
console.log("My var: "+process.env.MY_VAR);`

shows: 'My var'

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you invoking your `file.js` ?

Comment: What is in your file.js... make sure you are not overwriting `process.env` anywhere...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bashrc` is executed when you start a terminal session which is a child of current user session.

So... the user sessions outside the terminal have no idea about anything in `.bashrc`.

Now... your node console runs inside the user session of current terminal.

So... if you run a `js` script outside a terminal session, it runs in with a new copy of user's session.

So... you will need to create your variables in `.bash_profile` which is executed on user login... and everything there is effective for whole user session.

Comment: Great lesson. Fixed, Thank you!